# .htaccess, deny to download files within a directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to deny everyone to download anything inside the "attachment" directory.

My website structure is:

```
    public_html
    -img
    -css
    -root
    --attachment
    ---(numeric id)
    ----(files)
    -js
```

What I am trying to do is, to deny access to root/attachment/*/*

I tried many things, but I don't know why, I cannot get it working, my last tried was:

## .htaccess - on main directory.

```
    <FilesMatch "root/attachment/.*/.*">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all 
    </FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 17):

`FilesMatch` doesn't work with directories.

Create a new `.htaccess` inside `root/attachment/` as

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

Redirect rules specified in a parent directory `.htaccess` apply to its sub-directories as well. In case, these access rules do not work the same way, just move the `.htaccess` directly into `files` directory.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that inside attachment I will have folders with each record id and inside each folder it will contain the files. Is it the only way? Should I create a .htaccess on each folder?
Thanks :)

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas Start with this file in the attachment directory. I'm hoping the access rules should trickle down to sub-directories. If that doesn't work then we would need to configure your `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: this was the only option that worked for me. nobody says elsewhere that `FilesMatch` doesn't work with directories and `DirectoryMatch` doesn't work with files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new htaccess file /root/attackment/.htaccess and add the following lines

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

Comment: will it allow my script to access that file... and also it will not be dowanloadable from the URL ...?